# .NET port forwarding issue

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I try to create ssh tunel in my application and access remote mongo from CLI.

*The ssh server on remote host listening on port 9901

Remote Mongo port: 27017

Local host have: Windows 10, VS 2019

Assembly Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0

Remote host is Debian 9.9*

I success to access if I do port forwarding from Cygwin, but failing if I do it from C#.

**Scenario 1**

Open port forwarding:

```
ssh -p 9901 -L 50001:localhost:27017 user@host.net
```

Connect Mongo from localhost:

```
c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo --port 50001 --host localhost
MongoDB shell version v3.6.13
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:50001/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
WARNING: No implicit session: Logical Sessions are only supported on server versions 3.6 and greater.
Implicit session: dummy session
MongoDB server version: 3.2.11
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
>
```

**Scenario 2**

Code for port forwarding:

```
namespace VT_lic
{
    public static class PortForwarding
    {        
        static SshClient client;
        static ForwardedPortLocal portFwld;

        public static void Connect ()
        {
            PasswordConnectionInfo conn = new PasswordConnectionInfo(
                "host.net",
                9901,
                "user",
                "password"
            );

            client = new SshClient(conn);
            portFwld = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 50001, "host.net", 27017);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying SSH connection...");
                client.Connect();
                Console.WriteLine(client.CreateCommand("ls").Execute());

                if (!client.IsConnected)
                    throw new Exception("Kosha ssh connection failed");       

                client.AddForwardedPort(portFwld);
                portFwld.Start();

                if (!portFwld.IsStarted)
                    throw new Exception("Kosha port forward failed");

            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Kosha port forward failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

> backup
>   mk.sh
>   temp
>   file1
>   file2

Connection to Mongo:

```
c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo --port 50001 --host localhost
MongoDB shell version v3.6.13
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:50001/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
```

Netstat:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -a -n | find "50001"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:58045        127.0.0.1:50001        SYN_SENT
  TCP    [::1]:50001            [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

I tried all options:

```
new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 50001, "host.net", 27017);
new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 50001, "localhost", 27017);
new ForwardedPortLocal(50001, "localhost", 27017);
new ForwardedPortLocal(27017, "localhost", 50001);
new ForwardedPortDynamic("localhost", 27017); // --port 27017 in CLI also
```

Comment: I assume you shouldn't use 'localhost' in ForwardPortLocal method, try to use '127.0.0.1' instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like

```
string boundIP = "127.0.0.1";
string boundPort = "5477";

PasswordConnectionInfo connection = new PasswordConnectionInfo(server_config.Get("server_ip"),Convert.ToInt32(server_config.Get("ssh_port")),server_config.Get("ssh_user"), server_config.Get("ssh_password"));            
    SshClient client = new SshClient(connection);
    client.Connect();        
    //forwardIP = 127.0.0.1 
    // hostIP = 127.0.0.1 because I assume you want to access db which is running on 127.0.0.1
    ForwardedPortLocal forwardedPortLocal = new ForwardedPortLocal(forwardIP, Convert.ToUInt32(forwardPort), "127.0.0.1", Convert.ToUInt32(server_config.Get("database_port")));
    client.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPortLocal);
    forwardedPortLocal.Start();
```

Comment: Thanx!!! It seems, that host need be ip - 127.0.0.1, and not localhost. also I used Convert.ToUInt32() and 4 digit port num.